# The App Engine app associated with this project has been deleted

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine

The message displays on dashboard:

The App Engine app associated with this project has been deleted.

App Engine services malfunction in project number 502019044490

Answer (score 1):

It seems you [shutdown](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-projects#shutting_down_deleting_projects) your project. You can still restore the project within 30 days after the project has shutdown. Here is the [link](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6251787?hl=en#restore-projects) for more details about restoration.